# Automatic \newpage before every theorem

Tags: theorems, amsthm

Using `amsthm` package, is there an elegant way to automatically get a `\newpage` before every theorem?

Edit: MWE featuring Christian Hupfer's suggestion

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
% \makeatletter
% \g@addto@macro{\thm}{\clearpage}
% \makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
There are infinitely many prime numbers.
\end{thm}
% \newpage

\begin{thm}
$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: assuming your theorem environment is called `theorem`, `\makeatletter\g@addto@macro{\theorem}{\clearpage}\makeatother` should work... however, this is untested -- as usual, provide a compilable document, please

Comment: that doesn't work very well, I get "Theorem x.y" in one page and the body of the theorem (i.e. the stuff between `\begin{thm}` and `\end{thm`) in the next.

Comment: It was a guess only. Again: Providing a document is the better way to help us to help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the definition of `thm` as done by `amsthm` is a little bit tricky, I suggest to use the `etoolbox` package and add

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{thm}{\clearpage}
```

This is safe and will add the clear page before the theorem headline (and not disrupting the display)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\AtBeginEnvironment{thm}{%
  \clearpage%
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{thm}
There are infinitely many prime numbers.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know this isn't related to the original question, but what is the difference between `\clearpage` and `\newpage`?

Comment: @noibe: A `\clearpage` will always issue a new page and emitting all pending floats before, i.e. the will be flushed to the previous page, then the page break occurs. A `\newpage` for example will not eject a new page in case of being specified in a column setup, it will end the local column only then. In most cases `\clearpage` is the right approach... For instance, I can hardly remember setups where I needed `\newpage`